# Trying to open device manager from cmd

Tags: windows-10, device-manager

I have trouble booting my computer but I have access to cmd, in particular, X:\windows\system32\cmd.exe.

However, when I try to open device manager typing devmgmt.msc, I get the error: devmgmt.msc is not recognized as an internal or external command. How do I open device manager?

Comment: Can you open it in normal way from start menu? Does other management console file (.msc) open? Alternatively, try this command `%SystemRoot%\system32\mmc.exe devmgmt.msc`

Comment: You are booted in to a recovery environment. The running operating system is not yours, but a recovery environment. It is limited in scope and function. devmgmt.msc doesn't exist in that environment, and if you did open it, it would open for the recovery environment OS, not your native OS. I'm not aware of a way to do this. You do, however, have full access to your registry and file system. Perhaps a better question would be about solving whatever issue it is that led you to try this?

Comment: Check your `PATH` variable, which should include `system32` in the main windows directory, and make sure that `devmgmt.msc` is there. If not, locate `devmgmt.msc` and either type its full path or add its location to `PATH`.

Comment: @Appleoddity Please see here: https://superuser.com/questions/1239948/from-battery-plugged-in-but-not-charging-to-critical-process-died