# From "battery plugged in but not charging" to "critical process died"

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery, hp-pavilion

I have a windows10 hp pavilion laptop.

For my laptop before, I had the error "battery plugged in not charging" when my battery had around 30% left and I followed the steps https://superuser.com/a/777827/331921 to get it to work again. However, this time, I didn't do it and the battery went down to 0%. When I try to reboot it, it leads to critical process died loop and now I'm not sure what to do.

None of the recovery methods work so far, including system restore, reset pc, enter safemode ... etc. Not sure what I can do now.

Comment: Make and model of laptop? How old is it? Have you replaced the battery?

Comment: @CharlieRB HP Pavilion. 1 year old. No I haven't. Don't think it will matter in this case because the new problem is critical process died. When it was 30% battery, all I had to do was uninstall the battery drivers

Comment: Have you tested your hard drive in any way? A "Reset PC" is going to reinstall Windows and fix whatever problems you have. If that doesn't work then there is a hardware issue. I'm curious why you are associating the battery issues with this new issue? Is there something you did that you think is related? This system sounds like it has issues, first the battery now this. It should've been sent back under warranty.

Comment: @Appleoddity I read somewhere that said that one of the causes of critical process died was improper shutdown of the computer which I presumed was caused by the battery reaching 0%. It doesn't allow me to "Reset PC" right now. How do I test my hard drive?

Comment: The way your question reads, it sound like the laptop is dead, or won't power on. So, you are able to power on the laptop?

Comment: @CharlieRB The battery is at 0% but the laptop can power on through the charger.

Comment: In your comment above, you said it is only a year old. Is it still under warranty?

Comment: @CharlieRB So there is no way to access my drivers from where I'm at? I think the problem is caused by one of my drivers and if I can re-install the driver, I can fix the problem. The only problem is I can't go into safemode.

Comment: Could I try to use like Hiren's Boot CD?

Comment: You can try it the boot CD. Not sure you will be able to access what you seek. I would suggest using your Windows DVD or a recovery drive - [Recovery options in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12415/windows-10-recovery-options).

Answer (score 0):

My laptop is Acer Aspire V5, had an error battery plugin but not charging. Been a couple of weeks and then my laptop went to loop with 'critical process died'. It even went to point that my Windows 8.1 run a HDD scan (my Samsung Evo - I replaced it with SSD). I noticed that everytime it reboot, the battery charge LED indicator flashes and then went off. Fixed this by removing the battery and reboot my laptop. Works like magic now and my worry now is to buy a new battery.